# Close Vista gadgets from an another application

Tags: windows-vista, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have created a sample gadget (of course using google :D). It shows "Hello World!". 
I have created a .gadget file for installation of this gadget.
I have written an application that does ShellExecute to install this gadget.
I can see my hello world gadget.
Fair enough. And good lessons learnt.

Now I would like to write another application that closes this gadget and removes it from the sidebar.
 
Is there any **programmatic way** to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this. It is to emulate user action for closing the gadget.
Following is the script.

> function StopGadget(GadgetName) 
>   {
>  var WshShell = new
>   ActiveXObject(\"WScript.Shell\");
>   
>   WshShell.AppActivate(GadgetName);
>   
>  WshShell.SendKeys(\"+{F10}C\");
>   
>  WshShell = null; 
>  }